# JSON and WebMatrix - building a JSON variable

Tags: json, razor, webmatrix

I am writing some code for my application to send emails using SMTP headers.

The application i am using (Mandrill) expects to receive a JSON formatted object life this:

```
X-MC-MergeVars: {"var1": "global value 1"}
```

How would i write that as a variable in Webmatrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"var1", "global value 1"}};
var json = Json.Encode(d);
Response.Write(json);
```

UPDATE following your latest comment:

You can provide as many additional headers as you like. The WebMail.Send method's `additionalHeaders` parameter accepts a `List<string>`

```
var myHeaders = new List<string> {"X-MC-MergeVars: {\"var1\": \"global value 1\"}"};
WebMail.Send(foo: foo, bar: bar, additionalHeaders: myHeaders);
```

Comment: but i need to include the "X-MC-MergeVars" tag in there too, so that my SMTP provider knows what the JSON values are for?

Comment: This link might help you understand what i'm trying to achieve http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-

Comment: and i'm using that in conjuction with the webmail.send helper in Webmatrix. By the looks of it, i can't add more than 1 header, so i'll have to bundle it all into 1 string.

Comment: @Gavin5511 Updated my original answer in response to your latest comment.

Comment: Thanks Mike, works a treat (again). Can i also add more than one header like this? **additionalHeaders: header, myheaders** as that just gives me an error. Or do i literally need to add everything to a list, and just submit that as 1 header?

Comment: You add all the headers to one list and pass the list in.